# How to get iOS app install referral link in appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes-store, install-referrer

I am building eCommerce platform.This includes website,android app and iOS app.

I already implemented for Android by using Google Play Install Referrer API.For Android,when users install from a referral link,we will get referral link and other data and match that when user sign up in our app.So,we can count referral score.

I searched for iOS solution,but i'm not getting any proper solution.

What should i do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is about as good as you can get.

Go to appstoreconnect > App Analytics > choose app > Acquisition > Campaigns > Click the Plus icon and enter a campaign.

Basically, when you post your appstore link, add a ct=something parameter and you'll see installs from people who followed that link.

Comment: can i  receive this ct=value param in app after install?

Comment: no it does not seem to be possible. I am all for privacy but I think Apple goes to far here. There are legitimate use cases for install attribution beside its constant misuse by the ad industry. Imagine a QR code for a venue when scanned and the app is not installed, redirects to the App Store. Then when you open the App this venues screen pops up in the app. Its possible with Google Play referrer but nothing similar exists on iOS :(

Answer (score -3):

You can do this via [Deep Linking](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content). 
You can generate referral URL with some info such as `https://my.referal.app.com/referal?referalId=1`.Then when another user open this URL, it automatically will redirect to your app. And you can get `referralId` value in `App Delegate` in method  `open(_:options:completionHandler:)`

Comment: But this isn't what they asked, is it? They want to know which link triggered the install, not the application startup. And as far as I understand, this is just not possible.

Answer (score -3):

You can make this through **Universal Links Concept**

**Link Here**:https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/

Comment: Could anyone explain why is this answer downvoted? Is it because it's too short and doesn't provide clean explanation? Or is there something inherently wrong with using Universal Links to solve this problem?

Comment: In the meanwhile, I've learned the answer to my question myself. While Universal Links can support both cases: 1. "app is installed -> go to app" and 2. "upp is uninstalled -> go to WWW", and even in the case no. 2 the WWW page can redirect to App Store, there is no way to propagate Universal Link's path/params in the case no. 2. So Universal Links themselves don't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: There's a third-party solution by Google called "Firebase Dynamic Links" which _kind of_ supports propagating custom data in the case number 2, but it relies on *clipboard* (!). (Ab-)using clipboard has at least non-optimal user experience on iOS 14+.